# how can we use switch ,Edit Text and button in a single row of a table layout using java code?

Tags: android

i want to know the code to implement this 
how can we use switch ,Edit Text and button in a single row of a table layout
so that these three things come in a single row using table layout using java code

Comment: Second time you have posted this question.

Comment: i don't know how to code this using java code in android..!!!!

Comment: first time i have not got the correct answer

Comment: @CodeKing It was a corrected answer. What's wrong with it???

Comment: @Piyush  Sir I wanted to know it by using table View and you have answered using Linear View

Comment: @CodeKing So its compulsory to use Table Layout?

Comment: @Piyush sir yes it is Compulsory...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends Activity {
LinearLayout mainLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    TableLayout ll = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Hello");

    Switch s = new Switch(this);
    s.setTextOff("Off");
    s.setTextOn("On");

    EditText edt = new EditText(this);
    edt.setText("Hello Piyush");
    tr.addView(b);
    tr.addView(s);
    tr.addView(edt);
    ll.addView(tr);

    mainLayout.addView(ll);
}

}
```